# Unable to send data multiple requests in a single connection — socket error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, https

This question came from my previous ones. I need to some data to a server **multiple** times (2 times in this particular example) in one time:

```
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("www.site.com")
conn.connect()
conn.putrequest("POST", path)
conn.putheader("Content-Type", "some type")
fake_total_size = total_size / 2  # split a file into 2 parts

conn.putheader("Content-Length", str(fake_total_size))
conn.endheaders()

chunk_size = fake_total_size
source_file = open(file_name)

#1 part
chunk = source_file.read(chunk_size)
conn.send(chunk)                         # ok!
response = conn.getresponse()
print response.read()                    # ok!

#2 part
chunk = source_file.read(chunk_size)
conn.send(chunk)                         # OPS! [Errno 32] Broken pipe
response = conn.getresponse()
print response.read()

source.close()
```

That is to say, I want to send multiple requests in a single connection without closing or recreating it.

Note that the error is not because of the server's failure for sure, it's because of a **socket**, but why?

How do I get rid of the error?

**UPDATE**:

the same error:

```
#1 part
chunk = source_file.read(chunk_size)
conn.send(chunk)                         # ok!
 #response = conn.getresponse()
 #print response.read()
```

**UPDATE2:**

Still no luck:

```
conn.putheader("Connection", "Keep-Alive")
#.........
chunck_count = 4
fake_total_size = total_size / chunck_count   

for i in range(0, chunck_count):
        print "request: ", i
        chunk = my_file.read(chunk_size)
        # conn.putrequest("POST", path) -- also causes the error
        conn.send(chunk)

      response = conn.getresponse()
      print response.read()
```

**response**:

```
request:  0
request:  1
request:  2  # --> might not even exist sometimes
Unexpected error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Answer (score 2):

The connection was closed because you called `conn.getresponse()` and the server closed it. There isn't much that you can do about it from your side of the connection aside from passing a `Connection: keep-alive` header and hope that the server will comply.

If you want to send another HTTP request, you have to start with `conn.putrequest("POST", path)` or something similar.

Comment: @Mataba: HTTP doesn't work like that. You get a response only after you send a request.

Comment: I send a request, I read a response. Now I need to send another request without recreating a connection and read from it again. How?

Comment: Even if I comment the first "response = conn.getresponse()" and "print response.read()", it throws the same error.

Comment: @Mataba: What versions of HTTP does your server support? `getresponse()` keeps the connection open only if the server supports it. You may want to pass a keep-alive header as well.

Comment: @Mataba: Is this your actual code? You can't send a file in chunks like this. Pass a file handle to `.send()` and Python will chunk it automatically.

Comment: @Mataba: Pass the file handle instead of the contents of the file, which you get by calling the `.read()` method on the file handle.

Comment: "Pass a file handle to .send() and Python will chunk it automatically" -- it says "broken pipe"